# What specifics do models need to have to estimate the maximum acceleration my printer can withstand?

Tags: calibration, acceleration

Previous questions on the topic of setting acceleration are:

[How to theoretically calculate the maximum acceleration?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11407/how-to-theoretically-calculate-the-maximum-acceleration) (theoretical calculation)

[How do I determine the acceleration value for my printer?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/212/how-do-i-determine-the-acceleration-value-for-my-printer) (how to find the maximum value, in general)

The topic of the test model to use to stress the printer has not been touched yet.

So, when I want to test experimentally a printer according to the link above to have it skip steps due to excessive acceleration, what features does a model need to have for this to work?

To the extent it may matter, in my case I have a CoreXY printer with Bowden setup, so the stresses on X and Y direction are relatively comparable, the difference is only the weight of the X rods and holder (150 g max).

The firmware I use provides this model to test ringing:

[image]

Would that be suitable to stress-test the skipping of steps or should I consider making my own, and if, what features should it have?

Comment: "Which models" is overly borad. "What specifics does a model need to test for X" would be better

Comment: Does your printer have moving bed or just moving toolhead? Direct drive or bowden? These answers affect the order of magnitude you're looking for and thus to some extent test methodology.

Comment: @Trish edited accordingly

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I think the question should be generic, but I added the information anyway

Comment: @FarO shifted focus a little to make it more generic - AFAIK, The main feature should be short movements perpendicular to a movement. Everything else is driving the acceleration settings up with each subsequent layer.